# Compute the probability $P(Y>X)$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables, $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y \sim $Uniform$(0,1)$, compute the probability $P(Y>X)$.

I know this is a double integral over the area but I am unsure what the boundaries are on the integrals.

This is what I have now,

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{x}^{1}f(y)f(x)dydx$

But I am not getting anywhere with this...

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is Even(0,1) distribution?

Comment: Uniform distribution

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent,
$P(Y>X) =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-\infty}^{y}g(x)f(y)dxdy$
where $g$ and $f$ represent the $pdf$ of $X$ and $Y$  resp.

Comment: What is the definition of function $f$?

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thanks for pointing out, I have edited it now

Answer (score 1):

$P(Y>X)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-\infty}^{y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$ $dxdy$,

where independence of $X$ and $Y$ is assumed. In general, the integrand is the joint density which in this case can be split into $2$ because of the independence.

The problem with your representation is the $x$ in the integral (I'm refering to the $\int_{x}^{1}$ bit) -  if it is negative, then the pdf of the $U[0,1]$ is $0$, so it shouldn't be taken into account. Instead, it should be $\int_{\max\{0,x\}}^{1}$

Comment: When I integrate this bit: $\int_{-\infty}^{y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$ it should give the CDF for the normal distribution or N(y)-0, then I have to integrate again, is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: @John Yes, using integration by parts, and the result is [here](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=CDF%5Bnormal+distribution%2C+mean%3D0%2C+sd%3D1%2C1%5D-1%2Fsqrt%282*pi%29%2B1%2Fsqrt%282*pi*e%29).